# Can't close frame in java?

Tags: java, swing, awt, frame, windowlistener

Hi guys I am writing a little program in java and it's my first try at anything with an interface/picture.

It makes the frame for me but when I click the close button X, it doesn't close it just treats it like nothing happened...any ideas?

```
class Graph extends Canvas{

    public Graph(){
        setSize(200, 200);
        setBackground(Color.white);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Graph gr = new Graph();  

        Frame aFrame = new Frame();
        aFrame.setSize(300, 300);       
        aFrame.add(gr);       
        aFrame.setVisible(true);

    }
```

Comment: You need to setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE)

Comment: i would recommend look also at javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is that java.awt.Frame? I think you need to explicitly add the handler for so:

```
frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
  public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we){
    System.exit(0);
  }
}
```

I used [this](http://www.roseindia.net/java/example/java/awt/AwtCloseButtonEvent.shtml) source for so.

If it were swing it would be something like `jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE)`

Answer (score 1):

add `aFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);`

Comment: How come this works?...
`aFrame` is a `awt frame` and not `Jframe`.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Graph extends Canvas{

public Graph(){
    setSize(200, 200);
    setBackground(Color.white);
    addWindowListener( 
              new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
                public void windowClosing( java.awt.event.WindowEvent e ) {
                  System.out.println( "Closing window!" );
                  dispose() ;
                  System.exit( 0 );
                }
                }
            );
}

public static void main(String[] args){

    Graph gr = new Graph();  

    Frame aFrame = new Frame();
    aFrame.setSize(300, 300);       
    aFrame.add(gr);       
    aFrame.setVisible(true);

}
```